# Error when opening the mainform before subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to open mainform before the subeform  (why?)

My form need 6 seconds to load and show the form and subform to the user .I read that when  at first the mainform is loaded and then the subform and tits Data are loaded  ,the opening time could be better(less than 6 seconds)  hence I tried to implement this scenario:

I dleted the value of **Sourceobject** in the my subform property and add this block of code in mainform:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
Me.TimerInterval = 0
Me!ufrm_bauteile.SourceObject = "ufrm_bauteile"
End Sub
```

I set the Timerinterval in my mainform Property to 1.Logicaly I think it should work fine but an error Occure (error number 2467):

**The Expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist**

How can solve this Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first open a form, the following events occur in this order:

> Open → Load → Resize → Activate → Current

I would advice you not to set the timer, but to load the subform in your Load event handler.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me!ufrm_bauteile.SourceObject = "ufrm_bauteile"
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Absolutely, On_Load is also better than On_Open as it ensures the parent form is loaded first before attempting to load the sub-form. (Or at least in the case of bound forms)

Comment: thnk you both,I think in my mainform I have some Objects that are that refer to a subform objects hence occure that error.If I put this code in Form_Load(),is that problem solved? and does this Idea improve the performance?